# How do I use SVN Status command

Tags: svn

How do I use the `svn status` command in Subversion 1.7.2..

I tried the below command but din't work..

```
C:\Documents and Settings\dj91358>svn status  https://svn.nam.nsroot.net:9050/svn/33561/OpicsPlus/Opics/trunk/OPXPNYP/INTERFACE/RISK/
svn: E205000: Try 'svn help' for more info
svn: E205000: 'https://svn.nam.nsroot.net:9050/svn/33561/OpicsPlus/Opics/trunk/OPXPNYP/INTERFACE/RISK' is not a local path
```

Answer (score 5):

`svn status` gives status of the local working copy. It is not to be supplied a repo path.

Try

```
cd /path/to/working/copy
svn status
```

or

```
svn status /path/to/working/copy
```

Comment: it says :Q:\OPICS\Change_Control\OpicsPlusSVN\Opics\TAGS\OPXPNYP\OTHERS>svn status
svn: E155036: Please see the 'svn upgrade' command
svn: E155036: Working copy 'Q:\OPICS\Change_Control\OpicsPlusSVN\Opics\TAGS\OPXPNYP\OTHERS' is too old (format 10, created by Subversion 1.6)

Comment: @DJ_VJTI - Looks like you are using svn client 1.7 and working copy was checked out with 1.6. Either checkout afresh or run `svn upgrade` like it says.

Comment: when i run "svn upgrade" it prompts me a windows error :Q:\OPICS\Change_Control\OpicsPlusSVN\Opics\trunk\OPXPNYP\OPXSYS>svn upgrade
svn: E235000: In file 'C:\csvn\requirements\subversion\subversion\libsvn_wc\entries.c' line 1666: assertion failed (parent_node || entry->schedule == svn_wc_schedule_normal)

Comment: @DJ_VJTI - Ask that as a separate question. Or try checking out fresh  if that is fine.